# Starting new activity using onOptionsItemSelected with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm a newbie trying to learn Android Studio using Kotlin. My `onOptionsItemSelected()` is responding to the activity I set it to. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also, is `onOptionsItemSelected` the best way to go about having a responsive navigation bar?

I've tried implementing several options suggested by Stack Overflow, but most of them are either several years old or didn't work on my case.

[Starting new activity from onOptionsItemSelected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167647/starting-new-activity-from-onoptionsitemselected)

[How to implement a onMenuItemClickListener in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691788/how-to-implement-a-onmenuitemclicklistener-in-android)

These two threads are two of many examples that I've tried to use.

**First Activity**

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_second2.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class SinglePlayerActivity1 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second2)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_menu2, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId){
            R.id.ic_home -> {
                startActivity(Intent( this, MainActivity::class.java))
                true
            }
            R.id.ic_people -> {
                startActivity(Intent( this, TwoPlayerActivity1::class.java))
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

**nav_menu2.xml (menu)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        android:title="Home"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_people"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_people_24"
        android:title="Two Players"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</menu>
```

**activity_second2.xml (layout)**

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu2" />
```

**Manifest**

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TicTacToe">
        <activity android:name=".TwoPlayerActivity1" />
        <activity android:name=".SinglePlayerActivity1" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

[image]

Two items (home and two players) from the menu aren't responsive.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? What are the expected and actual behaviors? Nothing seems obviously wrong here. You have an odd naming convention for your menu item IDs. I see they are named `ic_home` and `ic_people`, and the `ic_` prefix is usually for drawables ("ic" stands for "icon") but this shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding. I edited the post with a picture, hope it clarifies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `supportActionBar?.hide()` which makes me think you're not using the Activity's built-in ActionBar. Are you using a Toolbar? You need to call `setActionBar(toolbar)` or `actionBar = toolbar` (Kotlin) if you want it to hook it up to the `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` callbacks.

Edit:
You're using BottomNavigationView, so in that case you probably don't want to use Toolbar or the onOptionsItem system at all, and use OnNavigationItemSelectedListener instead. Check this out for more info: https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android#using-bottom-navigation

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into Toolbar!

Comment: Hey man, it works! thank you :) enjoy your holidays!